# Coq: Error in coercion definition

Tags: definition, coq, coercion

Can you fix the error:

```
Parameter Arg: Type.
Parameter F X XP: Arg.
Parameter Sen Phy Leg Inf: Arg -> Prop.
Parameter tree car: Phy X.
Parameter mary john: Phy XP /\ Leg XP /\ Sen XP.
Fail Coercion c (u:Arg) (x y z: Arg -> Prop) (t:x u /\ y u /\ z u): x u := fun t => @proj1 (x u) (y u /\ z u) t.
(*The type of this term is a product while it is expected to be "x u".*)
```

I'm getting the same error when I take the term from

```
Coercion f (u:Arg) (x y z: Arg -> Prop) (t:x u /\ y u /\ z u): x u. tauto. Defined. Print f.
```

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: your `fun t => @proj1 (x u) (y u /\ z u) t` term is of type `x u /\ y u /\ z u -> x /\ u`. You want the whole coercion to have type `x u`, so you need to feed your function a term of type `x u /\ y u /\ z u` in order to get a `x u`.

I think you got confusion because of the `fun t => proj1 t`. To avoid confusion, you can rename this variable with a fresh name, like `fun foobar => proj1 foobar`, and you'll see that you never actually use your `t` argument.

Therefore, the whole term is `(fun t => @proj1 (x u) (y u /\ z u) t) t`, and it work for a `Definition`. But in the case of a `Coercion`, I get the following message:

```
c is defined
Warning: c does not respect the uniform inheritance condition

Error: Cannot find the target class.
```